# Unable to deploy docker solution with conda-forge

Tags: docker, vagrant, conda, conda-forge

I am deploying a docker solution for my application. In my docker file I used multiple conda-forge to build some containers. It worked very well for some of the containers, and give an error for the other and I am sure it is not about the package, because for the same package sometimes it work and others no.

I have tried to use pip instead of conda, but that lead to other errors since I am using conda originally for all of my configuration. Also, I read that `RUN conda update --all` will solve it, and for pip setup `RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools`

This is part of my docker file :

```
FROM dockerreg.cyanoptics.com/cyan/openjdk-java8:1.0.0
RUN conda update --all
RUN conda install -c conda-forge  happybase=1.1.0 --yes
RUN conda install -c  conda-forge  requests-kerberos
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install  kafka-python
RUN pip install requests-negotiate
```

The expected result is to build all containers successfully, but I am getting the following:

```
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 82f4cd49037d
     Step 14 : RUN conda install -c conda-forge  happybase=1.1.0 --yes
     ---> Using cache
     ---> c035b960aa3b
     Step 15 : RUN conda install -c  conda-forge  requests-kerberos
     ---> Running in 54d869afcd00
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/opt/conda/bin/conda", line 7, in <module>
     from conda.cli import main
     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
     The command '/bin/sh -c conda install -c  conda-forge  requests- 
     kerberos' returned a non-zero code: 1
     make: *** [dockerimage] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the error indicates the wrong path for conda `/bin/sh`

Therefore adding the proper path to the Dockerfile will solve the issue as following :

```
   ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/env/bin:$PATH
```

A good reference to related topic is here, where it suggests to create a new virtual environment within the dockerfile:

https://medium.com/@chadlagore/conda-environments-with-docker-82cdc9d25754

Answer (score 1):

Try combining the two `conda install` commands into a single command: `RUN conda install -c conda-forge happybase=1.1.0 requests-kerberos --yes`.

I ran into a similar issue with the install commands split up; it turns out the issue was that the first caused the python version to be upgraded, which in turn was incompatible with the `conda install` command - causing the error you're seeing.

Another workaround I found was to add `python 3.6.8` as another install arg. One of the packages I was installing must have had a python 3.7 dependency, forcing it to upgrade python, and breaking `conda install`.